# Adsorption of Cu2+ using banana peels for pH 2,2.5,3,3.5,4

Tags: experimental-chemistry, adsorption, uv-vis-spectroscopy

so basically I did my experiment which is the title. This is my procedure and results:

1. Make 0.05M CuSO4
2. pipette 50ml CuSO4
3. change to respective pH values using HCl
4. Add 2g of oven-dried banana peels
5. wait for half an hour
6. Filter the solution into 100ml volumetric flask
7. add 5ml of 2M HCl to change all replicates to approx. pH 1
8. top up to 100ml mark using deionized water
9. mix well
10. put solutions into cuvettes and place the into the UV-vis spectrometer to measure absorbance
11. compare it with the calibration curve to determine concentration

my 入max was 811.
For those wondering why I made all the replicate the same pH after filtration, it was so that the pH at the end would not affect the absorption value, because I found out that pH changes the colour of the solution.

results:
[image]
edit: so the first reading is a blank, the 2nd reading is the absorbance of the pH 2 solution after it has been made to pH 1, the 3rd reading is the absorbance of the pH 2.5 solution after it has been made to pH 1, the other readings are for pH 3,3.5 and 4 (in order). The K*abs value doesn't matter.

[image]
calibration curve:

[image]
[image]

Does this look right? Cus I can't find any research papers that do this. The ones that I found do pH 2,3,4,5,6 and use extremely small concentrations of CuSO4, something like 0.0002M. Even if u assume the trend will be the same, my results don't follow the same trend, which is that the concentration of CuSO4 left in the solution after the experiment decreases as pH increases. Basically it means that at a higher pH, the banana peels can adsorb more Cu2+ ions.

Comment: You do not give us enough information. For example, the first image reports 6 absorbance measurements, 1 to 6. But are they related to the same sample ? Are they related to different samples ? What are their meanings ? What should we do with theses values ? What is the meaning of K*Abs being always zero in this image ? Why is there no information about pH ?

Comment: ahh ok. I'll put more info

Comment: @Maurice I added some explanation below the first picture. To ans ur qn about what to do with those values, it is in steps 10 and 11

Comment: I would say that the absorbance does not depend on the pH value, and that the unknown sample has a concentration of 0.02 (unit unknown)

Comment: @Maurice that's not really what I'm asking. I want to know if the results look ok? cus i found this journal that says my trend (in the excel table) should continue going down.
https://www.geomatejournal.com/sites/default/files/articles/227-234-3c-anwar%20hossain.pdf

Comment: @ Brien. Are the samples measured in the first table identical or different ? Is it the same sample measured at different moments ? Is it a test for checking if the technique is reliable ?

Comment: @Maurice The samples in the first table are different. The first reading is a blank(just deionised water). The subsequent readings are the samples with different pH. They are in the order of pH 2,2.5,3,3.5,4.

Comment: @ Brien. The absorbance does not seem to be related to the $p$H. The absorbances values are changing randomly. If you repeat the same series of measurements with another series of samples, do you obtain the same values ? I doubt it. I have a feeling that the only differences between these absorbances are random. And that that all may be presented by : $0.25 ± 0.02$.

Comment: @Maurice I've done some research and quite a few studies have said that the concentration of cu2+ left in the solution should decrease as pH increases. They don't use uv-vis though, cus the concentration they use is extremely small. However, if they did use uv-vis, they would have gotten decreasing absorbance as pH increases. But I don't know if that applies to the concentration I'm using

Comment: @ Brien. Who is "they" who "don't use UV-Vis" ? You have modified the pH between 2 and 4. Why ? And I repeat : Have you tried to repeat the same series of measurements, just to see if your experimental values are reproducible ?

Comment: @Maurice "they" are the people who have done the paper/journal that i linked. I modified my pH between 2 and 4 because i need 5 data points, and the first time i asked a question on chem stack exchange, i asked if it was possible to get pH 5&6 CuSO4 and u replied no. I have not repeated it, cus this is actually graded, so there's like a fixed amount of time that i can go to the lab. But I might try to see if i can go again. But for now i just wanted to know if my results were even remotely correct

Comment: @Maurice i also wanted to know if my experimental procedure was ok. cus i can't find any procedures online that i could follow even though there are quite a few experiments like mine, that change pH, but they use a different heavy metal solution and different biosorbent